# Change of variables - integrals

Tags: calculus, integration, improper-integrals, absolute-value

\begin{equation}
\text{Let $\hspace{3mm}$  }f(t) = 2\int_{b}^{\infty} \sqrt{\frac{1}{2\pi t}}e^{-x^2/2t}dx.
\end{equation}
 I found that this integral can be written with change of variables can be written as,
\begin{equation}
f(t) = \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}\int_{|b|t^{-1/2}}^{\infty} e^{-x^2/2}dx.
\end{equation}
I guess the transformation used is $u(x)^2 = \frac{x^2}{t}$ so that $|u(x) | = \frac{|x|}{\sqrt{t}}$ . Is $u(x)$ 1-1? how we calculate the derivative of $u$ with respect to $x$. Can anyone explain analytically?

Answer (score 2):

Use the transformation $u=x/\sqrt{t}$ instead.  What you have, by the way, is just a normal (cumulative) distribution function.